# Compare data from two tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have two tables(Comment & Evaluation) and I want to do the following mySQL query into codeigniter. 
Here is the mySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT source) AS NumberOfEvaluations 
FROM COMMENT , EVALUATION
WHERE evaluation_id = EVALUATION.id AND EVALUATION.department_id = '$department_id' ;
```

And here is the closer that I reached:

```
$this->db->select('count(DISTINCT(source))');  
$this->db->from('comment','evaluation');  

$this->db->where();  

$query=$this->db->get();  
return $query->num_rows();
```

My question is what should I check in the where clause in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this code:

```
$this->db->select('count(DISTINCT(source))');  
$this->db->from('comment c','evaluation e');  

$this->db->where('c.evaluation_id','e.id');
$this->db->where('e.department_id', $department_id);
```